# How to configure SQLMap to attack JSON parameter?

Tags: sql-injection, sqlmap

Part of a box I'm doing, I can successfully pass basic SQL query `'or'1'='1` with no errors,

```
{"search":"'or'1'='1"}
```

Output:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
```

---

Trying to error the query

```
{"search":"'"}
```

Output: (successful)

```
HTTP/1.0 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
```

Using SQLMap with --risk=3 --level=5 won't do as the server immediately blocks a large amount of request in a small amount of time.

Comment: You may have to manually inject this. There are many places you might find SQL injection that require manual query construction.

Comment: HTTP/1.0 ? ....

Answer (score 1):

There is a little mismatch between the heading and the description of the question. From what I can get, there are two questions which I'll try to answer.

**How to configure SQLMap to attack JSON parameter?**

*Assumption: There is a `POST` endpoint that has a parameter named `search`*

1. Copy the RAW HTTP request in a text file(let's call raw.txt) that looks like this:

> ```
> POST /someendpoint
> Host: localhost
>
> {"search":"test"}
> ```

2. Run `python3 sqlmap -r raw.txt -p search`. You may also add --risk or --level.

**How to get around with server blocking request?**

This is a little bit tricky because it will require manual assessment as mentioned [here](https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/issues/3922).

*Assumption: As you mentioned "server immediately blocks a large amount of request", I am assuming you got this information by running SQLMap which gave this:*

```
there is a possibility that the target (or WAF/IPS) is dropping 'suspicious' requests
```

*Assumption: The 500 HTTP response means that the server is vulnerable to SQL injection.*

In order to solve the server blocking problem, we need to rotate the IP addresses. One way to do this is to install tor proxy and setup IP rotation in it. Then start SQLMap with `--tor` option.

1. Install tor on Debian Linux are:

   `sudo apt install tor`
2. Follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6405720/8325910) to setup IP rotation in tor.
3. Run `python3 sqlmap -r raw.txt -p search –tor –tor-type=SOCKS5`

Answer (score 0):

Any luck with **--delay**?

```
    --delay=DELAY       Delay in seconds between each HTTP request
```

Note that something else might also cause 500 error code.